# How can I remove these "steps" between faces from the mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

I'm having some troubles with this mesh in a project I've been assigned to. What can I do to make it smoother between these faces?

Object mode view:

[image: Object Mode]

Edit mode view:

[image: Edit Mode]

Thanks!

Comment: "*What can I do to make it smoother between these faces?*" Use [proper topology](https://topologyguides.com)

Comment: Topology is not a coat you put on an object, it is your object. Avoid long faces, subdivide them. Avoid those big triangles and use quads. The main problem is that because you have such large areas that are not planar you will be facing very marked transitions in areas that should look smoother.  Faces do not bend, you need to create a lot more vertices that describe the transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into edit mode. Hold your cursor over one of the long edges and hit 'Ctrl-R' to add an edge loop.  See where that loop is added. If it stops at the edge of the triangle, that is OK.  Keep adding edge loops between the top and bottom 'curves.' If the edge loops stopped at the triangles, do the same to the right and left 'legs,' with the same number of edge loops added.  Go into 'point/vertex' mode, select two points to bridge, and press 'F' to bridge them with an edge. You will have to subdivide edges in the middle of the triangles in order to get movable geometry in those areas. Continue doing this for a while and massaging the position of those points in XYZ space until you are happy with the surface flow.  That massaging can be done in edit mode, or you can jump over to sculpt mode.